# Tomcat 10 service won't start on windows

Tags: java, tomcat10

So I've downloaded and installed Tomcat10 service with:

```
PS C:\apache-tomcat-10.1.7\bin> .\service.bat install
```

and I can see it in my Services Windows page:

[image]

I've added two env vars:

```
PS C:\apache-tomcat-10.1.7\bin> $env:CATALINA_HOME
C:\apache-tomcat-10.1.7

PS C:\apache-tomcat-10.1.7\bin> $env:CATALINA_BASE
C:\apache-tomcat-10.1.7\instances\instance1
```

plus I've added `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin` to `PATH` env var

but when I give:

```
start tomcat10
```

a cli window opens for a split second, then closes.

I go look at the services page and tomcat service is not started, evidence also here:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Service tomcat10

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  tomcat10           Apache Tomcat 10.1 Tomcat10
```

I've looked around, and found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647003/cant-start-tomcat-as-windows-service) and I've changed the startup and shutdown from jvm to java but it didn't work.

So I looked at the logs:

```
[2023-04-05 10:55:42] [info]  [ 6304] Apache Commons Daemon procrun (1.3.3.0 64-bit) started.
[2023-04-05 10:55:42] [info]  [ 6304] Running Service 'Tomcat10'...
[2023-04-05 10:55:42] [info]  [ 6488] Starting service...
[2023-04-05 10:55:42] [error] [ 6488] Invalid JVM DLL handle.
[2023-04-05 10:55:43] [error] [ 6488] Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.
[2023-04-05 10:55:43] [error] [ 6488] Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.
[2023-04-05 10:55:43] [error] [ 6488] Failed to load JVM DLL '(null)', home '(null)'.
[2023-04-05 10:55:43] [error] [ 6488] Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.
[2023-04-05 10:55:43] [error] [ 6488] Failed creating Java '(null)'.
[2023-04-05 10:55:43] [error] [ 6488] Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.
[2023-04-05 10:55:43] [error] [ 6488] ServiceStart returned 1.
[2023-04-05 10:55:43] [error] [ 6488] Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.
[2023-04-05 10:55:43] [info]  [ 6304] Run service finished.
```

So I did override the defaul `jvm.dll` location to the one of Java 8 (the one I use):

[image]

Started the service again and in `commons-daemons.2023-04-05.log`I get:

```
[2023-04-05 11:36:31] [info]  [24996] Apache Commons Daemon procrun (1.3.3.0 64-bit) started.
[2023-04-05 11:36:31] [info]  [24996] Running Service 'Tomcat10'...
[2023-04-05 11:36:31] [info]  [15668] Starting service...
[2023-04-05 11:36:31] [info]  [15668] Service started in 8 milliseconds.
[2023-04-05 11:36:31] [info]  [24996] Run service finished.
[2023-04-05 11:36:31] [info]  [24996] Apache Commons Daemon procrun finished.
[2023-04-05 11:37:10] [info]  [17896] Apache Commons Daemon procrun (1.3.3.0 64-bit) started.
[2023-04-05 11:37:10] [info]  [17896] Running Service 'Tomcat10'...
[2023-04-05 11:37:10] [info]  [ 6052] Starting service...
[2023-04-05 11:37:10] [info]  [ 6052] Service started in 6 milliseconds.
[2023-04-05 11:37:10] [info]  [17896] Run service finished.
[2023-04-05 11:37:10] [info]  [17896] Apache Commons Daemon procrun finished.
```

but the service is still down... and looking at `tomcat10-stderr.2023-04-05.log` I have:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
2023-04-05 11:37:10 Apache Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized.
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)

    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)

    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again

Exception in thread "main"
```

which, I guess, means it didn't like the jvm I set up for it in the last step... help me out here pls.

Comment: Hi, java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Above exception clearly says classes are complied with java11 instead of java 8. 

Please try to uninstall java 11 then start the service.

Comment: had no idea ```java class file version 55``` means java 11, I'll try it out thanks

Comment: If you are using Tomcat 10.1, then you need Java 11.

REF: https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.1.html

Comment: @seenukarthi both your comments answered it, I guess I need to downgrade.
Thanks

Comment: As documented on [Which Version?](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) Tomcat 10.1 requires Java 11 or higher.

Comment: yeah no I got it, I meant I need to choose a lower version of Tomcat